# How to put the Javascript running time in an INPUT tag

Tags: javascript, html, input

Credits to the person I get this Javascript code for running time (Cleared my history and forgot the site, so sorry.) Javascript code for getting time.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function DisplayTime(){
    if (!document.all && !document.getElementById)
      return
    timeElement=document.getElementById? document.getElementById("mytime"): document.all.tick2
    var CurrentDate=new Date()
    var hours=CurrentDate.getHours()
    var minutes=CurrentDate.getMinutes()
    var seconds=CurrentDate.getSeconds()
    var DayNight="PM"
    if (hours<12) DayNight="AM";
    if (hours>12) hours=hours-12;
    if (hours==0) hours=12;
    if (minutes<=9) minutes="0"+minutes;
    if (seconds<=9) seconds="0"+seconds;
    var currentTime=hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds+" "+DayNight;
    timeElement.innerHTML="<font style='font-family:verdana, arial,tahoma;font- size:12px;color:#E25984; font-weight:bold;'>"+currentTime+"</b>"
    setTimeout("DisplayTime()",1000)
  }
  window.onload=DisplayTime
</script>
```

My form:

```
<form class="signin" method="POST" action="testVal.php">
  <span style="margin-top:15px; float:left;">Time</span>
  <input name="times" type="text" id="mytime" value="<?php echo $mytime ?>" />
```

The time is working but this is in PHP to get the time and needs to refresh. What I want is a running time in Javascript that doesn't need to refresh and indeed it's working but only in `<p>` and `<h1>` tags (in what I tried). It displays the time dynamically.

```
<p>Current time:</p><p id="mytimes"><p>
```

Aside from the input tags I don't know how to display the javascript in HTML Input tag. I tried some but it displays blank. I need it to be displayed in an INPUT tag for some reason.

Any revisions or suggestions will help.

Your help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what are you expecting by doing `<?php echo $mytime ?>`? Your script is javascript, not php.

Comment: It was just a test. I can display time using php in INPUT TAG. And can't get through with the Javascipt. 

javasript to INPUT tag. It is possible right?

Comment: document.all? It is not 1990 and more. font? same thing. That is some bad code you found.

Comment: I forgot <?php echo $mytime ?> come from here
 <?php
  date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
  $mytime = date('h:i a', time());
 ?>

Answer (score 1):

For an input tag, the `innerHtml` attribute is improper. Use the `value` attribute instead:

```
timeElement.value = currentTime;
```

If later on you wish to apply some styling, use CSS instead:

```
timeElement.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
timeElement.style.fontFamily = 'Verdana';
timeElement.style.fontSize = '12px';
timeElement.style.color = '#E25984';
```

Answer (score 0):

***The html:***

```
<form class="signin" method="POST">
    <span style="margin-top:15px; float:left;">Time</span>
    <input name="times" type="text" id="mytime" value=""/>
</form>
```

***The js:***

```
window.onload=setInterval(
    function DisplayTime(){
        if (!document.all && !document.getElementById)
            return;
        timeElement=document.getElementById? document.getElementById("mytime"): document.all.tick2;
        var CurrentDate = new Date();
        var hours = CurrentDate.getHours();
        var minutes = CurrentDate.getMinutes();
        var seconds = CurrentDate.getSeconds();
        var DayNight = "PM";
        if (hours<12) DayNight = "AM";
        if (hours>12) hours = hours-12;
        if (hours===0) hours = 12;
        if (minutes<=9) minutes = "0"+minutes;
        if (seconds<=9) seconds = "0"+seconds;
        var currentTime = hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds+" "+DayNight;
        timeElement.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
        timeElement.style.fontFamily = 'Verdana';
        timeElement.style.fontSize = '12px';
        timeElement.style.color = '#E25984';
        timeElement.value = currentTime;

    },1000);
```

***The fiddle:***

http://jsfiddle.net/dAcwu/1/

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
> function DisplayTime(){
```

By convention, identifiers starting with a capital letter are reserved for constructors. Plain functions names should start with a lower case letter.

```
>    if (!document.all && !document.getElementById)
>    return
>    timeElement=document.getElementById? document.getElementById("mytime"): document.all.tick2
```

I doubt that there are any browsers in use that require *document.all*, you can kill two birds with one stone doing:

```
    var timeElement = document.getElementById && document.getElementById("mytime");
    if (!timeElement) return;
```

.

```
>  var CurrentDate=new Date()
```

Note that variable names starting with a capital letter are, by convention, reserved for constructors. And since this variable is internal and it is quite clear that it's a date object, and the only date object in this function, consider making the name shorter for convenience:

```
    var d = new Date();
```

.

```
> var hours=CurrentDate.getHours()
> var minutes=CurrentDate.getMinutes()
> var seconds=CurrentDate.getSeconds()
> var DayNight="PM"
> if (hours<12) DayNight="AM";
> if (hours>12) hours=hours-12;
> if (hours==0) hours=12;
> if (minutes<=9) minutes="0"+minutes;
> if (seconds<=9) seconds="0"+seconds;
> var currentTime=hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds+" "+DayNight;
```

You can make all that a lot shorter with a small helper function to pad values and some handy operators and methods:

```
function addZ(n){return (n<10? '0' : '') + n;}
var h = d.getHours();
var ampm = h < 12? 'AM' : 'PM';
h = h % 12 || 12;
var timeString = [addZ(h), addZ(d.getMinutes()), addZ(d.getSeconds())].join(':');
```

.

```
> timeElement.innerHTML="<font style='font-family:verdana, arial,tahoma;font- size:12px;color:#E25984; font-weight:bold;'>"+currentTime+"</b>"
```

All that styling should be applied to the containing element directly, and the HTML is invalid anyway (the font tag was deprecated in HTML 4 and is removed in HTML 5, tags are not balanced). Rather than replacing the innerHTML, you can provide a robust *setText* function to set the text content of an element (see below).

```
> setTimeout("DisplayTime()",1000)
> }
```

Don't pass a string to *setTimeout*, it is passed the Function constructor and is a slow and inefficient way to pass the function, just pass a reference. Also, set the function to run just after the next full second. So the full function becomes:

```
// This looks long winded, but it provides a robust way to set
// the text content for any browser in use. Since this uses a
// function expression, it must be before any code that calls setText
var setText = (function() {
    var div = document.createElement('div');

    if (typeof div.textContent == 'string') {
      div = null;
      return function (el, s) {
        el.textContent = s;
      }
    } else if (typeof div.innerText == 'string') {
      div = null;
      return function (el, s) {
        el.innerText = s;
      }
    } else {
      div = null;
      return function (el, s) {
        while (el.firstChild) {
          el.removeChild(el.firstChild);
        }
        el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(s));
      }
    }
}());

function displayTime(){

    var timeElement = document.getElementById && document.getElementById("mytime");

    if (!timeElement) return;

    var d = new Date();
    function addZ(n){return (n<10? '0' : '') + n;}
    var h = d.getHours();
    var ampm = h < 12? 'AM' : 'PM';
    h = h % 12 || 12;
    var timeString = [addZ(h), addZ(d.getMinutes()), addZ(d.getSeconds())].join(':') + ' ' + ampm;
    if (typeof timeElement.textContent == 'string') {
      timeElement.textContent = timeString;
    } else if (typeof timeElement.innerText == 'string') {
      setText(timeElement, timeString);
    }

    // Schedule to run just after next full second
    setTimeout(displayTime, 1020 - d.getMilliseconds());
}

// Start when page loads
window.onload = displayTime;
```

And the HTML:

```
<div id="mytime"></div>
```

Comment: THANKS TO ALL :) TO RobG: How do you get the value from that DIV ("mytime") to the other page? I'm confused because how to retrieved that because we used Javasript (Not much have knowledge in JAVASCRIPT). Is it possible to display the time in 1stpage.php and get that time into the 2ndpage.php? Could you guide me 1 more time? Please.

Comment: If you are just displaying the current time, there is no need to move it from one pate to another, you just use the current system time. If you are sending a specific time from the server and want it displayed on the client, then you just need to work out the offset between the client and server (which should be an multiple of 15 minutes). Lastly, you can use a cookie to store some value from one page and read it from the next. But why not just send the value in the new page request and return it in the new page?